# I have no idea what the accept rate is or how to change it

Tags: support, stack-overflow, meta

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the acceptance rate and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/what-is-the-acceptance-rate-and-how-does-it-work)

I have no idea what the accept rate is or how to change it

Comment: *(related)* http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=accept+rate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell its the percentage of questions answered to answers accepted so start accepting answers and it will increase.

Comment: What if I dont find the answer usefull???

Comment: If you seriously can't find any answer of use then I would just delete the question.

Comment: I think there has to be another criteria for this Mate.. :( What If i didnt find the answer usefull? Unnecessary acceptance will exploit the spread of knowledge..

Comment: Hm That could be done.. Grt thanks

Comment: @James you cannot delete questions which have received answers

Comment: Thats even true, I agree with Gordon @Gordon

Comment: for example, James's answer is correct and helpful.  Your accept rate is a motivation for you to give him the credit he deserves for going to the trouble of answering your question.  Maybe wait a few days to see if a more eloquent answer appears from someone else.  You can find a list of questions youve asked in the profile area by clicking your name at the top of the page.

Comment: Then state why the answer isn't helpful/useful. Sometime this may be because the question has been misunderstood or doesn't give enough information.
Also if you manage to find your own answer then post it.

Comment: @James: why would you do that? Just wait. Or start a bounty.

Comment: @Gordon: not true...you can delete questions that have received answers.

Comment: All the discussion and The Answer Clarified my doubt thanks... Now need to fight any more.... :)

Answer (score 0):

The accept rate is the percentage of questions for which you have accepted an answer, out of the total number of questions you have asked. It is considered good form here to accept an answer to as many of your questions as possible, and in a timely manner.

If you don't find any answers to the question useful, you have a few options: if you've figured it out on your own, you can answer your own question and accept that answer. If you still haven't figured it out and still want an answer, you can set a bounty on the question for a certain number of reputation points, to stir up interest. Finally, you can always close or delete the question.

Comment: "in a timely manner." What do u mean by this?

Comment: There is no need to be "timely" - I'd encourage people to be laggardly, and in fact a new feature has been added to partially enforce this behaviour.