# My acceptance is stuck below 100% due to a migrated question

Tags: support, accept-rate

Here is the question that was migrated:

https://superuser.com/questions/96921/hr-management-what-are-some-good-open-source-or-cheap-solutions-closed

I'm unable to achieve 100% acceptance rate, because superuser.com does not allow me to accept an answer to that question, but it's still giving me credit for having an open question.

Is this a bug or is there a way around this?

Comment: I just want to mention, that you do not need to have a 100% acceptance rate. You are above 50%, so don't worry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should not actually be an error - according to the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/what-is-an-accept-rate-and-how-does-it-work/16729#16729), two of the criteria which prevent a question from counting on your accept rate are "Being closed" and "Having no answers". Your migrated question satisfies both of those, so it does not count.

Furthermore, of 14 questions asked you have only 11 eligible for accept rate (of which 9 are accepted - you can see this by hovering over your accept rate if you didn't already know). You have 1 question asked within 4 days that doesn't count, and 2 closed questions (including the migrated one). So that subtracts from 14 to yield the 11 questions remaining - the migrated one isn't counted.

...though fully reviewing your profile, you have 12 questions with accepted answers... so I'm not quite sure what is going on. But the migrated question should *not* be part of the calculation.

In the future, for a general scenario with migration stubs, as Bill the Lizard (theoretically might have) said, "The best course of action is to flag it for deletion". A migration stub is locked, so the only people who can actually affect it are the moderators. So to get the people who actually have power on the relevant site, the best course of action is to flag it for moderator attention.

**EDIT**

As random has now deleted your migrated post, your accept rate is still at 82% with 9 out of 11 eligible. Which means that the migrated post was not the reason your accept rate is below 100%. It is an error in the update of the display, not the presence of a migrated question.

Comment: You are incorrect on the accept rate. One of the questions is too new to be counted. When I have no open questions, I do not have a 100% accept rate due to the migrated question.

Comment: @hamlin If you hover over your accept rate, it literally says [you only have 9 out of 11 eligible](http://imgur.com/MWKvG.png). I also noted the question that is too new in my answer body. Like I said, I reviewed your profile - I know you satisfy 100% accept rate. But it doesn't change that your displayed accept rate is wrong.

Comment: This is definitely a caching issue.  I can't see the deleted stub anymore so I'm not sure what *exactly* the problem was.  If the question *had* answers before it was migrated it could have been counting against his acceptance rate, which only gets updated every day or two.

Comment: There were no answers on that stub before it was migrated and deleted. @bill

Comment: If that's the case then it wasn't even an eligible question for accept rate in the first place, before migration. Definitely a cache issue, as Bill states.

Comment: @Grace: My original answer was wrong so I deleted it.  You'll want to remove the reference to it.  You may want to just change it to a general suggestion to delete migration stubs, I'll leave the wording up to you.

Comment: @Bill: You delete answers I have upvoted? WAAAAAAAAAAAAAA!

Comment: @Ladybug: Sorry for making you waste a vote with my conclusion-jumping and ignorance.  I'm blaming this on a mental caching delay.  :)