# What is meant by acceptance rate?

Tags: support, accepted-answer, accept-rate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is an accept rate, and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/what-is-an-accept-rate-and-how-does-it-work)

Hi I am a newcomer. Many people have helped me out many times. Recently I came to know about acceptance rate to reward my responders, but I don't know how...

Comment: Shouldn't this be community wiki?

Comment: @Nathon: why should it be? OP is just asking what acceptance rate on Stack Overflow is and how it works. Nothing more.

Comment: I need to fix the main FAQ, which is apparently not linking the [accept rate FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/what-is-an-accept-rate-and-how-does-it-work).

Answer (score 4):

You ask a question and people answer. When you are happy with an answer you accept the answer. Sometimes you may not get a satisfying answer (rarely if you ask good questions!).

If you accept an answer for all of your questions your acceptance rate is 100%.

If you accept an answer for just half of you questions your acceptance rate is 50%.

To accept an answer you simply click the tick mark next to the large number of votes next to the answer (left column).

Answer (score 1):

Your "acceptance rate" is a measure of the amount of questions for which you have accepted an answer. You can accept an answer by clicking the tick to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to reward responses:

- upvote (as soon as you have 15 rep, see the [faq](https://stackoverflow.com/faq)
- accept one answer as the correct one, i.e. the one that helped you most (click on the checkmark next to it) See also [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)
- award one or more bounties (you need 100 rep for this)
- you can also leave a comment, but please only if it is more than "thanks" (upvote = "thanks" and suffices)

The *acceptance rate* is only a statistical number to show others how many of your questions have accepted answers (in relation to your total question count).