# What is accept rate and how do I improve it?

Tags: support, accept-rate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is an accept rate, and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/what-is-an-accept-rate-and-how-does-it-work)

I know this isn't a programming question, so I'll take it down soon, but I was told in one of my other posts that I should work on my acceptance rate... What is an accept rate and how do I improve it?

Comment: This should be asked on http://meta.stackoverflow.com
See StackOverflow's FAQ for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: It's good you know it's not a programming question- so you should ask this at http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ 

EDIT: StriplingWarrior beat me to it :(

Answer (score 3):

Marking questions you ask, as answered (by checking the little checkbox by the most helpful answer)