# Does closing my own question affect my acceptance rate?

Tags: support, closed-questions, accept-rate

Does closing my own question affect my acceptance rate? If so, how?

Scenario(s):

**Q:** What happens if my question has answers and I close the question?

**A:** It doesn't matter the status of answers: if it's closed, the question is exempt from being counted in the accept rate calculation.  ([Grace Note](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/146126/grace-note))

Comment: I had the answer, but then realized that it's not clear what you're asking.  Do you mean if you close some question is your acceptance rate affected, or do you mean if one of your questions is closed that it still counts against your acceptance rate.

Comment: Right, the former, Lance. Sorry, I'll update my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly.

Closed questions do not count towards calculating your acceptance rate. So having a question with no accepted answer closed could raise your acceptance rate.

You can see the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/what-is-an-accept-rate-and-how-does-it-work) for more details.

Comment: Actually closing a question *with* an accepted answer also may affect your accept rate. If you had 50% with 4/8 before, closing an accepted answer changes that to 3/7, which is lower!

Comment: What happens if my question has answers which I don't think are correct or helpful and I close the question?

Comment: @John Good luck closing a question for a frivolous reason like that instead of holding out for a better answer? To speak seriously though, it doesn't matter the status of answers: if it's closed, the question is exempt from being counted in the accept rate calculation, as stated here.

Comment: @Grace: Clearly a miscommunication between us, but I must ask, where do you get off judging people so quickly? My reasoning is not frivolous as much as it is based on experience. Anyone who has mastered their trade knows the difference between the right way of doing things and a workaround. When I say "answers which I don't think are correct or helpful," it is because I know they are workarounds. In my case, there has not been a positive correlation between time and the quality of answers that I have received, which is why I propose closing instead. Nevertheless, thank you for your help.

Comment: @John I will admit that frivolous may have been a harsh word on my part. Nevertheless, "not getting a real answer" is simply not a valid reason to close a question. We close questions because the question is off-topic, duplicate, or otherwise outside the scope of the site; closing blocks it from getting answers and is the first step towards deletion. The ineffective answers provided by our peers is not really qualifying to do that, especially because even if it doesn't help you right now or ever, someone in the future may come across it.

Comment: @John I am sorry if my comment came across as an insult to you. Since closing is a community process, though, I think it'll be difficult for you to justify actually closing a question for "lack of good answers".