# my accept rate is still 0%

Tags: support, accept-rate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is accept rate, and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/what-is-accept-rate-and-how-does-it-work)

I marked several answers to my questions as accepted but my accept rate is still 0%. Why?

Comment: @AlexR:It will take a while before SO recalculates it.By the way you should be asking such questions at http://meta.stackoverflow.com/.

Comment: Accept the answer by Svissstack ;)

Answer (score 6):

Wait some time!