# Notification when having low accept rate

Tags: feature-request, accept-rate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show alert for users with 0% (or low) acceptance rate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71334/show-alert-for-users-with-0-or-low-acceptance-rate)

I've read suggestions about preventing users from asking questions when they have a low accept rate. And I do agree that it will not help.

However, what about an notification (the orange top div) that shows a message like "We suggest that you start accepting answers, read more *here*". The link goes to a page describing the accept process in a **very** detailed way with lots of screenshots.

The nag notification should be shown now and then.

Might even encourage those who doesn't accept answers even though they know how to.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a good idea. I like it.

However if I may say so, such users already get manual "notifications" from the others.

Comment: Yes. But that will not help if they do not understand how to (or why they should)  accept answers. And it's not as annoying as the orange div ;) A detailed page would explain all that.