# Check mark discoverability seems to be low for new users

Tags: discussion, new-users

Has StackOverflow done any user interaction design studies targetting new users?

I've noticed that, quite frequently, new users don't appear to notice that they can accept answers by clicking the checkmark.

Here is the latest example:
[html footer don't seemed to stick at the bottom in Print Preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407742/html-footer-dont-seemed-to-stick-at-the-bottom-in-print-preview)

Note the user is getting comments on the fact that he has asked 10 question but accepted none. Then he replies that he was not aware of this feature.

I, myself, was not aware of the feature until someone pointed it out to me in a comment on the first question I asked.

Everyone who sticks with <strike>the forum</strike> SO eventually (& fairly quickly) gets this, but I suspect most do not realize it at first, and that a non-trivial number of users pose legitimate questions that get answered legitimately but never get accepted because the user does not stay engaged with SO for more than the first few questions asked.

---

**UPDATE** (in response to comments, and for clarification)

The issue may not be the *position* of the checkmark per se.

If there *is* an issue (and my primary suggestion would be to conduct a usability study focussed on new users to see if there is)
it may be that there needs to be more communication about the process to new users, e.g., a prominent note provided the first time a question is asked, or an *important* process overview page provided at account set-up. There currently is no official process overview presented anywhere, officially, on StackExchange web sites (as far as I have been able to find, and I just did a new account setup with my wordpress account just to see what's presented during that sequence.)

As one commenter pointed out, SO is not a "forum". However, I would conjecture  that it is prior experiences with forums that most users hold as a frame of reference when first approaching SO, and this feature, though it is out there (e.g. Yahoo Answers), is not particularly common on forum web sites.

Perhaps Yahoo Answers is a good model to look at. I would suggest they do a better job at making this feature obvious to new users by being more explicit with the "Best Answer - Chosen by Asker" label placed promenently on such answers. I should note that I am aware of this feature on Yahoo Answers even though I have never asked or answered a question there -- it's because I've come across these pages in my Google searches and the text makes it so obvious. SO/StackExchange sites could consider, as one possible option, being similarly more explicit.

I do not believe that *accepting answers* is a common interaction model across the world-wide web. StackExchange sites ought to put more into educating new/potential users about such features. The green checkbox is a bit subtle for someone who might otherwise be completely unaware that answers are "accepted".

But consider all this  just yakety-yack until a usability study is done.

Comment: See - http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/6211/improve-affordance-of-mark-as-answer-on-stackexchange

Comment: Please don't refer to [so] as a forum... [It is not a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128554/172936)

Comment: In my opinion it's in ideal position. Do you have any better suggestion?

Comment: As a side note, whenever one has trouble finding it give him/her [this link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it contains screenshot and really can't be any more clear than that.

Comment: Regarding your new update: Stack Overflow already shows the accepted answers first, always - even when it got less votes than other answers. [Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98426/) - I think anything  more than that (e.g. flashing signs or colors) will clutter the site too much and harm its professional look and feel. Yahoo Answers is a great example for highly **non professional** community, something Stack Overflow tries its best not to be..

Comment: @Sha Dow Wiz Ard: it's not that users know about this feature and cannot find it -- it's that they do not know about it at all. You've highlighted and important mistake in my post: the issue is one of *discoverability* (not findability)

Comment: In this case, there is already [pending request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79347/reminding-new-users-of-accept-upvote-duty) to improve this *discoverability* :)

Comment: @Sha professional?? How in the world are unicorns and waffles and ponies professional? Oh, that's meta. ;-)

Comment: Also @Faust - there are some good points about cases where OP won't accept an answer in [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/50468/152859) on other question. (disregard the question itself)

Comment: @Sha Dow Wiz Ard: Perhaps the Yahoo Answers soln doesn't fit -- but your concern can be accommodated while still doing a better job of educating new users (e.g.: providing a simple process overview at registration).

Comment: This is in the FAQ. What else do we need to do? Wrap it in a `<blink>` tag?

Comment: @The Estabilishment: It is burried in the faq toward the bottom of a section that must be clicked to open, under a heading that reads "How do I ask questions". Out of over 860,000 registrations on SO, only 18,303 -- just over 2% -- have earned the "Analytical" badge, meanging they have read every section of the faq.

Comment: @The Establishment: As for "What else do we need to do?" I've made a couple of suggestions already in my question. But I'm not suggesting we just pick up and go with one. SO has some preliminary/anecdotal evidence of a probable usability issue here. A *professional* approach would be to 1) conduct some usability analysis focused on new users, 2) determine more objectively whether there is an issue that is worth addressing, 3) design some alternatives 4) test them, and 5) implement the most effective soln.

Comment: @The Establishment: "...  In a locked filing cabinet in a disused lavatory behind a door that said 'Beware of the tiger'"