# What is use of accept rate now?

Tags: discussion, support, accept-rate

With the recent [January changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161595), it is given that

> 2013-01-22: Accept rates will no longer be shown. Like flag weight, they will continue to be calculated for backend use.

I would like to know if there are any visible effects to the users in anyway? And at the back-end, what would it be useful for?

Is it that a post from a user with better accept rate will be deemed as higher quality over the post from a user with low accept rate?

Comment: One possibility for future use is [Showing alert for users with 0% (or low) acceptance rate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/71334/152859), I noticed it wasn't declined just yet. (nor given official answer)

Comment: Check out [this discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165179/replace-accept-rate-with-citizenship-level).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We are not doing anything special with it right now. Certainly not using it to predict the quality of a post.

Many people with a high accept rate post things that aren't 100% fantastic. Their posts aren't necessarily *bad*, but someone's accept rate in no way guarantees that their posts will be better than others'.

This may change later, of course, but for the moment... it's simply hidden but tracked internally for potential future use.

Comment: And it's part of the API's interface, can't stop calculating it without breaking the contract... which isn't gonna happen.

Comment: And, as a trivial function of data that's _just there_, it's also... _just there_. Proposing to remove accept rate from the backend would be like proposing to remove the count of how many users SO has.

Comment: I would say that the "*accept rate*" was not meant to be an indicator for the quality of posts. I think it was something more like "Do I take the time to answer that question if maybe I don't get votes or the green checkmark?". Which might not have driven the right behavior sometimes.

Comment: Is it still tracked?

Comment: @M.A.R. It would be impossible to NOT track it. It's calculated from numbers you cannot avoid tracking.