# Does/could/should SE prompt users harder to vote on and accept answers to their questions?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

If I remember rightly, when I view a question to which I haven't yet accepted an answer, I sometimes see a reminder to accept an answer.

But I was wondering if SE sites could push users harder to return to questions that remain without unaccepted answers? Perhaps in the top-right another icon a bit like mod/edit queue. Perhaps when you post a question or accept an answer you could be prompted "what about these other questions you asked".

As a user on many SE sites, but some of them infrequently, and almost exclusively to ask questions, such a feature working across all SE sites would be kind of neat. e.g. I return to SuperUser site every 2 months with a question and remember to check my old questions rarely, but I am on SO several times a week so if SO prompted me about SU questions it might help.

Has this been discussed/trialled before?

Comment: It seems rather a shame that people have piled in to up-vote an answer that describes an _entirely_ different former feature, and down-vote my question presumably based on that misunderstanding.

Answer (score 8):

Yes we had it for many years. It was known as the [accept rate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/how-does-accept-rate-work). Every user had an accept rate and was encouraged to keep that high. [Penalties were proposed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71334/show-alert-for-users-with-0-or-low-acceptance-rate/90748#90748) for having a low accept rate.

In the end accept rate [was abandoned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136951/lets-stop-displaying-a-users-accept-rate) as it led to users badgering and harassing other users about accepting and focusing on that rather than just answering questions.

I don't think we want to go back to that situation where we already tried and failed.

Comment: Note that the current question/proposal is potentially very different from the previous situation with the accept rate. The system could remind users more often to accept answers, without the accept rate being public or any penalties being imposed.

Comment: The problems with the previous attempt were caused by other people being able to see the accept rate. The system reminding users to accept answers is not likely to cause the same problems. That does not go against the previous decision or ignores the bitter experience, because it is not the same thing.

Comment: We're still telling people accept rate is important. It simply isn't, in my opinion. Answers and questions are important as is voting but accept is something that happens once, voting has no limit.

Comment: My suggestion is very different to what is described above. It would be only visible to the _user_ as a gentle reminder. I often forget to revisit and select accepted answers myself, I can't be the only one.

Comment: But it encourages people to think that acceptance rate is important and we've seen that leads to poor behaviours.

Comment: @RobertLongson surely the entire concept of SE is built around accepting answers? You haven't demonstrated that it leads to poor behaviours you've demonstrated that making it public does. That's a cultural issue really. I don't even care what my % is, I'm purely suggesting users are reminded of 'open' questions.