# How many questions do I have to ask for my "Accept Rate percentage" to show up?

Tags: support, accept-rate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is accept rate, and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/what-is-accept-rate-and-how-does-it-work)

How many questions do I have to ask for my "Accept Rate" to show up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [How does accept rate work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/what-is-accept-rate-and-how-does-it-work/16729#16729),

1. "The accept rate is only calculated when the user has 4 or more questions."
2. "The accept rate is calculated on questions that are older than 3 days."

Comment: I have asked 8 questions on Stackoverflow.com but my accept rate does not show up still.

Comment: @Linuxmint: Because the last 6 questions are not 3-day old yet.