# Are there any tutorials with images that go over how to accept answers?

Tags: support, accept-rate, accepted-answer

In situations where new users don't know how to accept answers is there a basic tutorial with pictures that I can direct them to that explains how to accept answers?  Usually when someone asks how to accept answers I will post something along the lines of:

> Click the Check Box image that is in
>   the upper left hand corner of the
>   answer you want to accept.

But this may be confusing, especially for users who don't speak very good English (which seems to be a large portion of non-answers).

Comment: Hand drawn circles! We need hand drawn circles!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can direct them to the [appropriate FAQ question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: I've starting posting that link every time i post a comment saying "yo, your accept rate sucks...".

Comment: Or: to [an animated image](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/how-does-accept-rate-work/65088#65088).