# Accept rate problem

Tags: support, accept-rate

I've accepted all my questions. Why still it is 97%?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449849/slashes-in-html-mail

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794641/best-development-environment-for-php-closed

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3824714/ids-in-mysql-standard-ids-or-alphanumerics

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can list the questions you've asked that don't have accepted answers by searching for `user:me hasaccepted:0`. You can also toss in `closed:0` and `wiki:0`, since closed and CW questions [don't affect your answer rate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/what-is-accept-rate-and-how-does-it-work/16729#16729): https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:233286+hasaccepted:0+closed:0+wiki:0

It looks like you missed a couple questions:

- [IDs in MySQL, standard IDs or alphanumerics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3824714/ids-in-mysql-standard-ids-or-alphanumerics)
- [Slashes in HTML mail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449849/slashes-in-html-mail)