# how accept rate calculated

Tags: support, accept-rate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is accept rate, and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/what-is-accept-rate-and-how-does-it-work)

I don't to know how **accept rates are calculated**

My accept rate is showing 27% so I want to know how this rate is calculated?

Comment: thanks for quick response got the thing

Comment: @andy so if we are giving solution to other and if they are accepting ans then only reputation is increase ??no effect on accept rate???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the FAQ:

> When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer. This lets other people know that you have received a good answer to your question. Doing this is helpful because it shows other people that you're getting value from the community. (If you don't do this, people will often politely ask you to go back and accept answers for more of your questions!)

Comment: All true, except that people don't often ask very politely.

Answer (score 1):

Jeff Atwood explains the accept rate [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/new-question-asker-features/).  From that page, here are the basic rules for calculation:

- Questions must not be community wiki.
- Questions must not be closed.
- Questions must be more than 3 days old.
- Questions must have at least 1 answer.
- There must be at least four eligible questions as determined by the above rules, otherwise the statistic will not appear.