# Why do I have only a 92% accept rate on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, accept-rate

Afaik, I have awarded and answer to every question and would expect a 100% accept rate.

However, there have been some questions which were so esoteric that they got no replies or where I figured it out for myself before an answer was posted.

Could it be that the accept rate is calculated by # questions asked (ignoring deletions) and # answers awarded?

If so, should it be that way? (I'm not too concerned about my rate in asking how it should be, just genuinely interested in the reasoning)

Comment: See: [What is accept rate, and how does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/what-is-accept-rate-and-how-does-it-work) (you have to accept an answer to every [open, not CW and not deleted] question you asked in order to hit 100%)

Comment: Note to self., Search for `user:me answers:0`` - works for everyone, on every S.E site

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not accepted answers to [these questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A192910+closed%3A0+hasaccepted%3A0+answers%3A1+wiki%3A0). Only non-wiki questions with at least 1 answer and that are not closed are eligible. If you have discovered a solution, post and accept that solution.

Comment: @JeffM There should be 20 questions in that search. I saw that question in the listing - it stood out as it's the only question I've looked at and there was only one "visited" link. You can also doublecheck by hovering over the 91% - it says "205 out of 225 eligible", and there are 20 results on that page when I checked. You probably have one or more tags ignored among those questions, which may be hiding them.

Comment: +1 Thanks. I have tided up all of those and now have a 96% accept rate. I sthat beacuase I deleted some questions, or because I answered some of my own questions ?

Comment: @Mawg Looks to me like you have a 100% accept rate—may have just taken a while to update. FYI, Deleted questions don't count, self-answer is the same as any accept.

Answer (score 1):

it is `#answers accepted/from #of q asked/`

Comment: +1 for replying, but does # questions asked include those that were deleted?

Comment: it should not hopefully..