# Accept rate display bug?

Tags: bug, status-completed, accept-rate

I thought accept rate was only supposed to be shown if a user has [4 non-wiki questions older than 3 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/how-does-accept-rate-work).  I was looking at [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/60968/can-subcontractors-claim-contractors-work), and the user only has 2 questions, and one of those is less than an hour old.  Indeed, the tooltip says there is only one eligible question:

[image: screenshot]

Why is this user's accept rate being displayed?

Comment: we did refactor the way we store this ... may be a regression

Comment: Another example: http://stackoverflow.com/users/656848/user656848

Comment: And another: http://stackoverflow.com/users/666000/flaming-desriable-heart -- the accept rate itself is accurate, it just shouldn't be complaining for this user quite yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was my fault, we *totally* changed how this works on the back-end to optimize it.  Also, instead of a sliding expiration (with a pretty much unpredictable change time) that it was, this is calculated daily for all users.

However...yours truly lost the `>= 4` check on the question count when doing this, oops!

This will be fixed in the next build.