# Accept rate showing for user even if eligible questions are less than 4

Tags: discussion, bug, accept-rate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accept rate display bug?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84348/accept-rate-display-bug)

I thought accept rate for a user is always shown when the user has atleast 4 eligible questions to which the user has not accepted any answers.

However I just stumbled upon this user for whom the accept rate is showing when he has only 2 eligible questions. Refer snapshot below -

[image]

Is this a bug or some new feature has been introduced in SE sites?

Comment: Same question here: [Accept rate display bug?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/84348/155585)