# Why do some Stack Overflow users have an "Accept Rate" displayed below their name?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does accept rate work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/how-does-accept-rate-work)

Why is this visible for some, but not all, S.O. users? I know what's its for, just curious as to why some users have it and others don't.

Answer (score 1):

It appears below the people who have asked questions. If it doesn't display, I'm guessing they haven't asked any! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think that these are the only scenarios when you can see the accept rate (correct me, as I know I'm missing something):

1. The user is the person who asked the question you're browsing.
2. The user has asked at least one question, which is at least 2-3 days old.
3. They have a registered account (guests show up as just a gray username).