# Acceptance rate showing seemingly at random

Tags: discussion, feature-request, support, accept-rate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does accept rate work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/how-does-accept-rate-work)

It's good to be able to see somebody who has a low-ish acceptance rate before running off and doing a long answer that will likely never see acceptance/upvote or even a reply by the OP.

But I am not sure of the logic applied to pick which ones are being shown and which ones are not. Here are two examples:

Warning for 50% rate: [mootools and firefox 4 problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242388/mootools-and-firefox-4-problem)

No mention of acceptance rate: [Does someone knows why url: 'data.html' in Request.HTML won't work on some webhosts (when data.php does)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214096/does-someone-knows-why-url-data-html-in-request-html-wont-work-on-some-webhos)

Yet the latter OP I already know by reputation, she has had 5 questions thus far with 1 accepted answer, though 3 were answered. Anyway, that's irrelevant as the principle is what I am asking about:

When is the acceptance rate being shown and **why can't it always be shown** for people with multiple questions that have received answers? I realise that there is probably a grace period whilst the OP allegedly waits for answers on their recent questions so these need not be taken into account. 'Tumble weed' questions should not be taken into account either, I suppose but often these are a direct result of the reluctance of people to answer to somebody with a particularly low acceptance rate.

Comment: FYI: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/how-does-accept-rate-work#16729

Comment: cheers - this explains things somewhat, sorry for not looking harder at questions already answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) page, [How does accept rate work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/how-does-accept-rate-work).

Specifically, the acceptance rate only shows up when a user has at least 4 qualifying questions - those questions older than 3 days that have answers and are not community wiki.

For the latter example you give, that user has no rate given because two of their questions have no answers, so they don't have the minimum of 4 qualifying questions.