# How to identify 0% accept rate users

Tags: discussion, new-users, accept-rate

I've encountered users with several questions asked, all (or most) of them answered, but none accepted. Generally, they have few rep points (<100), so it's easy to mistake them for users who have just signed up; is there a quick way to identify such users (other than taking a look at their profile), who are not really newcomers to the site, but have not been accepting any answers?

Comment: From the above link: "If the stat doesn’t appear at all, it’s a new user, or someone who rarely asks questions". Right, but how do I identify users who rarely ask questions, and never accept them?

Comment: Not sure why my comment got deleted, [How does accept rate work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/how-does-accept-rate-work).  Why do you want to identify users with 0% accept rate unless you are looking at one of their questions? (i.e. what Bill is saying)

Comment: You could use the [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/) - the above link includes to algorithm used to work out whether someone has their accept rate displayed or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only users that don't display accept rate are those with less than 4 questions under their belt.  So, really, you're getting the accurate information for the majority of users.

If you want to look more precisely than that, it isn't too much of a detour to look at their profile.  It's often more telling (for example users may also have a lot of downvotes).  Otherwise, consider that it's frustrating to not get the checkmark, but you've done your duty in terms of answering the question for future users, plus you can still get a healthy number of upvotes from other people.

Answer (score 12):

If anyone finds a way to quickly identify users with 0% accept rate, please post it here so we can have it removed immediately.  The last thing I want to do right now is delete 30,000 *more* "Work on your accept rate." comments.

Comment: 71%? C'mon ♦-guy, you're supposed to be setting an example! ;)

Comment: For those of you with tons of rep, getting an answer accepted may not mean much - but personally, I get a little annoyed when I spend time helping someone and they won't even click a tick as thanks.