# How to Improve accept rate in Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, accept-rate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

When I'm trying to ask questions on Stack Overflow, I'm getting the following message:

You need to get your acceptance rate up & Work on your accept rate

Where do I have to go to do this and Tell me step by step.

Comment: 24 questions in 6 months, 0 accepts 0 votes.  You've spent enough time here to be able to spend a minute or two reading the FAQ I think.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Accept answers.  Click the green check next to the best answer to your question and it becomes the "Accepted answer".  Your acceptance rate is the percentage of question that you have asked for which you have accepted answers.

---

[image: screen shot and link to detailed explanation]

Comment: (exception to the accept rate are closed, Community Wiki, and unanswered questions, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/how-does-accept-rate-work/16729#16729)