# Looks like voluntarily in Vote up/down system

Tags: support, up-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What if I want to reverse my vote?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114676/what-if-i-want-to-reverse-my-vote)

With my reputation I can just vote up, not vote down.
By mistake I did vote up for some answer, after that I am not able to vote it down, or restore it to original state.
My friend is also facing similar issue.
If you vote down, it will be negative like '-1' and after if you vote up it will be '+1' not 0.
Is is programmed purposely?
I don't want to criticize anything or anyone, but I use this site daily, and it helps me a lot.
So I just want to make it better.

Comment: Click the "Up" arrow again to remove the upvote.

Comment: @Arjun , Yes its half of my asked question.Thanks.

Comment: There should always be *just one* question in a Q on a Q&A site, Debugger.

Answer (score 1):

After some time expired, up- and down- votes are [intentionally "locked"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18046/165773) no matter what rep you have - such are *rules of the game* so to speak.

The way to "tweak the system" is to edit the question/answer ("[suggest an edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)" in your case) - this "unlocks" the question and you can update your voting decision on it.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXH3l.jpg]

Comment: Thank you.It was really helpful.

Comment: @Debugger [you are welcome](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/110461/165773)