# Acceptance rate is missing for a certain user

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, accept-rate

Why is the acceptance rate of [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/399145/samselvaprabu?tab=questions&sort=newest) not displayed?

He has 9 questions, all with answers, two of them accepted, should be a rate of about 22%.

I checked the 3 newest questions, on none of them the rate was shown. For other users I am able to see the rate.

So what is special with this user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro), the accept rate shows up:

[image]

Accept rate is  calculated on questions that are older than 3 days and is heavily cached, according to this [faq](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/how-does-accept-rate-work).

Comment: OK, I was irritated, I saw he is a member for about 17 month, but I didn't realize that 7 out of his 9 questions has been asked in the last two days (!).