# How to accept unanswered questions

Tags: support, accept-rate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)
>   [How does accept rate work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/how-does-accept-rate-work)

If noone answers a question that I post, I can't accept an answer.  But then my accept rate sinks, and that might put people off answering my questions in the future :-(

Is there any way to "accept" unanswered questions?  My accept rate is only 80% but I would love it to be 100%...

Thanks
Ant

Comment: Don't worry about an Accept of "only 80%". That's perfect. I only become suspicious when I see an accept rate of <20. Either because the OP seems to randomly (not) accept questions, or because the OP seems to be unable to ask good questions.

Comment: @Rob W: That's far from perfect.`</rimshot>`

Comment: I thought that accepting the bounty on that one question would automatically mark it as accepted, but it didnt - thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to mark a question with an accepted answer if there isn't an answer to accept in the first place, so those questions shouldn't count into your accept rate at all.

You do have at least one question with an unaccepted answer. You can always mark that as accepted if you think it's good enough for you, then that'll bump your accept rate up to max. It's not *required*, though, so don't worry even if you decide not to accept it. Just *remember* to do this for any questions you have with answers that help you.

For what it's worth, an accept rate of 80% is really good. If it puts perfectionists off, that's their problem.

Answer (score 4):

Questions without answers don't count towards your accept rate - look at [my question list on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/153020/awoodland?tab=questions) for example: 9 questions, 5 have answers, 3 are accepted and I have an accept rate of 60%

Answer (score 1):

BoltClock and awoodland are right (it's just [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7216538/) that is "dragging down" your accept rate), but there are some things you can do to attract attention to your questions:

1. Edit to improve them.
2. Offer a bounty.
3. Share the link with friends or on Twitter, etc.

You should also:

1. Post your own answer if you've solved the problem
2. Delete the question if you've realized that the PEBKAC

Answer (score -1):

How could you accept an answer that doesn't exist?

If your question is unanswered, maybe its quality isn't good enough and you should considerate improve it or delete it if it's not improvable.

If you think that it is a really good question, then you can still offer a bounty on your question and get some attention that'll surely lead to an answer.