# Does deleting un-accepted answers increase acceptance rate?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does accept rate work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/how-does-accept-rate-work)

I am really wondering  if detecting my yet un-accepted answers improve my acceptance rate?

Comment: Slightly beside the point, but deleting questions or answers just to improve some meaningless statistic is **never** a good idea. If you delete too much of them, you might get question- or answer-banned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're confused about how the acceptance rate is defined.  It's not how many
of your answers have been accepted; it's how many answers you've accepted on questions you've asked.

So to answer your question, no, deleting your own unaccepted answers will have
no impact on your acceptance rate.