# Do migrated questions get counted in a site's the accept rate?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

Do the migrated questions from other SE sites get counted in, or have effect on, the site's accept rate?

Comment: What do you mean by accept rate? Do you mean your accept rate [like this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/how-does-accept-rate-work) or are you talking about answer percentage like [here](http://stackexchange.com/sites#oldest)

Comment: I meant like the first example you have referred to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/new-question-asker-features/), closed questions don't count for accept rate. Since migrated questions are closed, they won't count either.

To demonstrate that migrated questions are closed, you can use a search with `closed:1`. You'll see that migrated questions turn up. For example:
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Is+this+streamable+combination+of+encryption+and+MAC+secure%3F+closed%3A1

Comment: I am not sure. The questions are pointed as [migrated] and not [closed]. I did not find any reference in the blog to the migrated questions.

Comment: @Future2020 That's only a cosmetic title change. The system edits the title when a question gets closed. Originally it said [Closed] even for migrated question. But a migrated question is still closed.

Comment: @Future2020: A migrated question is technically closed as "off topic" on the original site *and* migrated.

Comment: Even if they wouldn't count as closed(I'm pretty sure they do), migrated questions get automatically deleted after a few weeks.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: hmmm, i am still seeing a migrated question which is not yet deleted as you suggest even after "few" weeks. I am still wondering if there is a more informing and decisive answer to this :)