# How can I increase my accept rate on SO?

Tags: support, accept-rate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does accept rate work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/how-does-accept-rate-work)

I'm sure this is pretty simple for the Pro's but I am starting to get more serious on SO and would like to be a valuable part of the community one day.

Thanks

Comment: Ask questions that get answers worthy of accepting. But seriously, don't worry much about accept rate, just contribute.

Comment: Accept some questions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your accept rate is exactly what it says: the rate at which you accept answers to your questions. You increase it by accepting more answers on questions you have asked.

Now, this does *not* mean you should accept any answer on your question. If you only got one answer and it was crap, ignore it. Your goal should *not* be a 100% accept rate. Accept rate is generally only a problem if it is less than about 30-40%. In those cases, it often indicates people who don't know that they should accept correct answers.

Your current accept rate is 59%, which is entirely reasonable.

I checked your history, and I noticed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404852/jquery-select-the-li-around-a-href-specific-url) where you seemed to [like one particular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10404877/734069), going so far as to [thank the person giving the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404852/jquery-select-the-li-around-a-href-specific-url#comment13422020_10404877). Yet you didn't accept it (which is the only form of thanks we really need).

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer.