# how do I "accept" an answer on stackoverflow?

Tags: support, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

I have gotten requests to "accept" answers to my questions, but I'm not sure how to do it. I've hit the up arrow...given positive comments as feedback... but how do I accept the answer?

Comment: [How to Accept Answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/65088)

Answer (score 0):

Click the checkmark next to the answer.