# How can I increase my accept rate for asking questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does accept rate work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/how-does-accept-rate-work)

How can I increase my accept rate for asking questions? And for each question, does the question rate differ ?

Comment: Your accept rate on SO is 100% though. Why asking? If the question is old enough, has an answer and you accept the answer, then it will be counted towards the accept rate. But don't just accept anything - only accept one that solves your problem, or brings you close to the solution.

Comment: [how-it-works](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/how-does-accept-rate-work)

Comment: And http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you accept an answer, your accept rate will improve. If you accept one answer for each question you have asked your accept rate will be 100%.

There is no difference on a particular site, although your accept rate may be different on different SE sites.

---

[image]

---

Comment: This did inspire me to find out which questions I hadn't accepted answers on and sort them out, so am now happily at 100%.

Answer (score 2):

Your accept rate is based on if you accept answers to your questions!

If you have asked 5 questions and accepted 4, your accept rate will be 80%.

However, you should only accept answers if they *do* answer your question. If you think no one has answered a question, you can answer your question yourself and accept that.

You will not get additional reputation for asking accepting your own answer, but it will keep your accept rate 100%.