# Answer accept rate not correct

Tags: support, accept-rate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does accept rate work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/how-does-accept-rate-work)

I have asked 8 questions till now, but have accepted the answers for just 6 of them yet, as I didn't find the satisfactory answer for the other 2.

But yet, on the tag on questions I have asked, it shows '100% Accept Rate'. Isn't this something wrong? It should be 75% in my case.

What's the logic behind calculating the accept rate?

Thanks

Comment: From the faq: *The accept rate is calculated on questions that are older than 3 days* - those two questions are not older than 3 days so the accept rate is calculated based on the other 6.

Comment: Hmm. Thanks a lot :)