# Do questions with no answers count toward my accept rate?

Tags: discussion, questions, accept-rate, no-answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does accept rate work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/how-does-accept-rate-work)

What if I have a question with no answers? If I don't receive an answer, will it affect my Accept Rate?

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta I don't think it's a duplicate of How accept rate works? It is like asking a question(my question) from any book(How accept rate works)...

Comment: It asks, and answers, your question, Akshay. I'm afraid I don't understand the rest of your comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. It does not count questions with no answers.
Look at the accept rate of [this OP's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12209324/how-to-set-password-for-a-database-in-ms-sql-server-2008). It's accept rate is 40%. Now hover to his accept rate it shows the following tool tip:

```
this user has accepted an answer for 4 of 10 eligible questions.
```

Now look at his [questions tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1394305/anujin?tab=questions). There are 13 questions. Where three questions have no answers. So accept rate is counted without questions with no answers.

Comment: Don't get "unanswered" confused with "without any answers."