# Why does my Stack Overflow account not show my accept rate?

Tags: support, accept-rate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does accept rate work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/how-does-accept-rate-work)

I have a significant amount of reputation on Stack Overflow. Yet my account still doesn't show the accept rate. Even though my answers have been accepted several times. What might be the issue? Do I have to gain more privileges for my accept rate to be visible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your accept rate reflects how you accept answers for questions you've asked. Not how many of your answers have been accepted.

Comment: okay Thanks Dmytro...!!

Answer (score 4):

You haven't met the conditions for it to be shown yet: [How does accept rate work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/how-does-accept-rate-work)

- The accept rate is calculated on questions that are older than 3 days.
- The accept rate is heavily cached and can take 24hrs or more to update. (See below.)
- The accept rate is only calculated when the user has 4 or more questions.

While you have 6 questions, three of them aren't older than 4 days yet, then you might get hit with the caching - after that, you should be sweet though.

When [Js file of ckeditor failed to load in codeignitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12157688/js-file-of-ckeditor-failed-to-load-in-codeignitor) is the one that is causing you to miss (shows it as 2 days old). Give it another day or two.

Answer (score 1):

The acceptance rate is for questions you have asked yourself. This is to make askers aware of the "Accept Answer" function, and to let answerers know when somebody is unlikely to accept an answer.