# How to know own Accept rate?

Tags: discussion, accept-rate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does accept rate work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/how-does-accept-rate-work)

I found that I see users Accept rate at bottom of every Question. But, I want know my own Accept Rate How I can know my own Accept rate?

Comment: You have to ask at least four questions and your questions have to be at least three days old before Accept Rate is shown.  You have four questions on StackOverflow, but one was posted only yesterday.  More information is available in the [Accept Rate Faq](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/how-does-accept-rate-work)

Comment: I already asked four questions on stackoverflow. But I can't see my accept rate. Is it necessary to have accepted answer for all questions?

Comment: Ah, I had just edited my original comment.  Your four questions have to be older than three days as well.  One of your questions was only posted yesterday, so wait a day or two and it'll appear.  Accepting answers won't affect whether it shows or not, it'll just affect the number (and a higher number often means you'll get fewer complaints from other users).

Comment: okay. Thanks for sharing information and quick response.

Comment: Note that you should not accept answers for the sake of your accept rate. If people bother you about your accept rate, please do flag such comments as non-constructive. *Only* accept answers that were *genuinely* helpful to you!