# Marking ANSWERED to questions raised by me

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, moderation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

I am sorry, this question may sound silly...
I am not able to mark questions posted by me as ANSWERED. Please help me - How do I do this...?

PS: Tagged to different communities for help!

Thanks a ton,
Mike

Comment: How long has it been since you posted the answer?

Comment: Which part of [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/65088/155831) is not working for you?

Comment: @Blender It seems [from this](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1629833/mike) the latest is around 48 hours old.