# The line with accept rate should be a link to the questions tab for the OP

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, accept-rate

This is similar to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/61981/132564), but the scenario and motivation are different and the proposed solution is therefore different.

Every other time I see a question of mine and see my accept rate next to it and find that my accept rate is too low (whatever that means) I go to my profile and from there I go to the "questions" tab and look at questions where I could accept an answer. This requires two clicks - first onto the link to my profile, then to the questions tab.

What if the link to the questions tab was right under the "X% accept rate phrasing" and only displayed to me? I could see that my accept rate needs work and go right to the questions list.

Comment: Do we really need that?    With those extra clicks you get at least some excercise.

Comment: Declined, given that [accept rate is no longer shown on the usercard for a question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164654/140951).

Answer (score 2):

Well, I see where you're going with this, but really the only "proper" place for that to link to would be a page that explains accept rate, [like this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/how-does-accept-rate-work).

If a user has 0 accept rate, linking to the questions page won't mean anything to him.

Comment: Well, you're right about users with 0 accept rate. Yet they are a separate problem. A differentiated approach is possible - a link to the page you suggest for users with low rep and a link that I suggest for users with high rep who already know what that thing is, just want to avoid an extra click.