# Accept rate should exclude viewed, unaccepted question

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, accept-rate

When viewing a question without an accepted answer. I want to see the asker's accept rate calculated without the current question.

After all, when considering answering someone's unanswered question, we want to consider their *other* questions. It's a bit silly that when a user has one open question, and you're looking at it, it counts against their accept rate.

Comment: I don't follow at all.  What should another user looking at it have to do with anything?  If you're asking whether an question without any answers should count against a user's accept rate, it doesn't.

Comment: Your first sentence seems like you're asking that a users accept rate should exclude unaccepted questions... that seems to be a contradiction.

Comment: The request, I believe, is for the displayed accept rate to exclude the question being looked at if does not have an accepted answer. I see no point in it.

Comment: A wonderfully succinct and accurate analysis @Mat.

Comment: Declined, given that [accept rate is no longer shown on the usercard for a question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164654/140951).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please have a look at [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/how-does-accept-rate-work)

The acceptrate is calculated only on questions that are 3 days old. So the first three days, it wont consider the current question. And after three days the question is seldomly seen on the front page. So I think the three days are more than enough.

Answer (score 2):

There's actually a group of individuals who are in fact pushing to have accept rate hidden altogether. For some reason, users seem to give accept rate a lot of misplaced weight when determining whether or not to answer a question. As a result, I don't really see Stack Exchange taking the time to implement this feature.

In reality, an accept is only a mere 15 reputation, and the asker can only award it once. It's really not a lot of reputation when you consider that a well-written post that helps future visitors -- of which there will be hundreds or thousands -- could yield the answerer many, *many* upvotes. The potential for reputation on a decent answer could be 30, 50, 100 reputation or even more!

Instead of focusing on accept rate, focus on the actual question. Is it something you can answer? Is something missing from the question that needs clarification, and if so, could you leave a helpful comment asking the asker to provide that information?  If all is in order, then answer the question. If it solves the asker's problem, they're likely to accept the answer. Maybe not today, and maybe not tomorrow, but that's okay. Remember, it's only 15 reputation.

Just this week, I saw in my reputation history that someone accepted an answer I wrote in March, over 7 months ago, and another was accepted that I wrote in April! When you've answered enough questions, even if you take a break, your reputation will continue to slightly increase, like interest paid on investments, and if I never took the time to answer those two questions because of accept rate, well, I would have lost 3 upvotes, plus the 2 accepts.

In summary, focus on helping people, focus on good Q&A, and the reputation will come. Don't harass people about their accept rate, and if you see these comments, flag them as noise. It's optional for users to accept an answer, and sometimes people won't know the answer worked for them until months later. So be patient. :)  Hope this helps!

Comment: It's not a matter of reputation, neither in this question nor on the site. It's about indicating which answers are correct. This allows future visitors to see instantly which questions were answered and which are still open. That's the point. That said, I'm among those who feel the accept rate should be hidden, and I always flag "increase your accept rate" comments.

Comment: Sure @MrLister, marking the correct answer is important, but I think you're missing the point. Is the green checkmark so precious that it's worth not providing an answer at all? The op seems to think it is:  *"After all, when considering answering someone's unanswered question, we want to consider their other questions.".*