# stackoverflow accept rate wrong

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does accept rate work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/how-does-accept-rate-work)

I've been off stackoverflow for a little bit and my rate was 100% when I last was on and was showing as 0. I accepted an answer today and only shows 17%. Did something happen while I was gone lol?

Comment: This is the first time seen someone comment on their own acceptance rate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have 6 questions that are 3+ days old with answers and you have one accepted answer.

`1/6 = 0.166666` rounded to `17%`.

Comment: Hmmm...but how was it at 100% before Christmas and now I have questions that are back to being accepted? Going back and accepting.

Comment: @Shawn The questions either did not have answers or they were not 3 days old.

Answer (score 1):

From [How does accept rate work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/how-does-accept-rate-work)

> ...
>   The accept rate is calculated on questions that are older than 3 days.
>   ...
>
> #### Which questions do not affect the accept rate?
>
> The following questions are not included in the accept rate calculation:
>
> - Community Wiki Questions
> - Closed Questions
> - Questions with no answers

Your accept rate used to be 100% because you had a number of questions that were too young to include or had no answers.  Now they're older and have answers, and your accept rate has been updated accordingly.