# What should we do with all questions related to accept rate?

Tags: discussion, meta, accept-rate

[Accept rate will no longer be shown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164654/187824). So now all the questions related to accept rate became obsolete. So what should we do with all questions related to accept rate?

Should these questions be deleted or locked?

For example FAQ question: [How does accept rate work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16721/187824)

Comment: If you look at the Meta front page, work is already in progress. (@casperOne at work it seems :) )

Comment: I think it's better to let mods handle the faq's, I know casper9 is already doing his part as we speak. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd casper9? The secret casperOne/Shog9 hybrid?

Comment: @Bart LOL!!! <blush> (I fixed it then added back for sake of... well, humor! :))

Comment: @Bart sssh we're not supposed to talk about that one in public yet

Comment: I would just mass-tag them with something like `[status:obsolete]`. I wouldn't delete them, as someone who participated positively in discussions about accept rate shouldn't get their rep taken away just because that feature got removed much later.

Comment: @Rachel If the question is older than 60 days the rep would remain afaik. But yeah, I wouldn't delete them either. And it seems that's not happening at the moment anyway.