# What to do with meta questions referring to currently non-existing features?

Tags: discussion, meta

I sometimes come across such questions like that:

["Not a real question." (Change to "Not a valid question.")](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17282/not-a-real-question-change-to-not-a-valid-question?rq=1)

The "Not a real question" close reason doesn't exist for long time. It doesn't make sense to answer, comment, or even up/downvote (since there's nothing more to vote for/against it).

Shouldn't such questions be locked as historical ones? Should I flag them for moderator attention or just ignore them?

Comment: `[status-obsolete]` or `[status-deprecated]` would be fine as tags, but these do not exist. Otherwise flag or close it as @AakashM indicates

Comment: Duplicate [What should we do with all questions related to accept rate?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164747/187824). But I am closing mine as it has no answer and is only asking for accept rate.

Answer (score 9):

The close reason

> **Off topic -> Can no longer reproduce** Changes to the system or to the circumstances affecting the asker have rendered it obsolete. If
>   you encounter a similar problem, please post a new question.

would seem to apply.

Comment: Closing the question will not prevent comments and voting, in that case meta-voting for obsolete feature...