# Accept rate and questions without a solution

Tags: discussion, support, accepted-answer, unanswered-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accept rate-why accept an answer that isn't an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27457/accept-rate-why-accept-an-answer-that-isnt-an-answer)

What should one do with questions that offer no solution. They may have some ideas, but non of them actually solves the problem?

Are there any other means of marking a question as something to make it as accepted, without accepting just something that's not an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are talking about two different things.  If somebody finds a question that matches his problem and the question has, say, 1000 views and none of the answer provide a conclusive solution then that is a valuable question.  You know you'd better start looking for another approach.

Not having such a question marked answered is utterly logical, there is no conclusive answer.  It would be nice if somebody posted that there is absolutely no answer and that answer could be accepted.  But that doesn't happen very often at SO.  It is far more difficult to prove that there is no answer.  And such an answer doesn't often get appreciated, I usually just skip them.

If your answer rate is what bothers you then you could yourself post an answer and draw the conclusion that there is no answer.  And accept it.  When you get a downvote on it then take another look.  Built-in notification for a better answer.

Comment: The trick with own answer as "none of the answers solve the problem" is a great technique in such situation. thanks for the hint.