# Responding to comments about 0% accept rate when I have no satisfactory answers

Tags: discussion, comments, accept-rate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)
>   [Accept rate-why accept an answer that isn't an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27457/accept-rate-why-accept-an-answer-that-isnt-an-answer)

I had a 0% accept rate up until a few minutes ago, purely because I have not received any suitable answers to my questions.

I asked a new, fairly innocuous question and got comments about my 0% accept rate.

I went and accepted an answer to a question that is not actually the correct answer in order to stop this happening.

Does this behavior harm the community?

Comment: Only mark answers as accepted if they help you answer your question.  If your questions are not satisfactorily answered, don't get pressured into just picking something.  A lot of times, people will get their questions answered but not mark anything and _that's_ what we really want to get marked.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9690425/352552) seems to answer your question -- why isn't *it* accepted?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9412572/352552) also.  But based on your comments, it looks like you wanted the person writing the answer to then answer something *else*.  It seems you need to try to ask more focused, clear questions that ask only *one thing*

Comment: *Does this behavior harm the community?* yes, yes it does.  Flag these comments and ignore them.  After flagging them.  Don't ignore them before flagging, otherwise you won't know to flag them.

Comment: @AdamRackis I was waiting for the 5 minutes to pass for the 1st one, and I tried the 2nd but it does not work at all.

Comment: @darryn.ten - you don't understand.  The problem with your second question is not that the answer is incomplete, it's that your **question** was bad.  If you have to leave comments with links to other pages describing what your problem is, then you've done a fundamentally bad job of asking your question.  The question itself should have everything the answerer needs.

Comment: @AdamRackis I see - so I should remove the question and rephrase it?

Comment: @darryn.ten - **don't** delete the question - it has an upvoted answer, and deleting your own questions can get you banned.  If the answer answers the question as originally written, accept it.  Then ask a new, crystal clear question that demonstrates exactly what you want.

Comment: @Josh - for sure - to delete the post darryn would have to flag for moderator attention.  I didn't mention that because I didn't think deleting was appropriate here.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you flag the comment as non-constructive / off-topic and it contains the words accept rate or some form of that, the comment will get deleted immediately.  I just removed the comment on your latest question as a test to make sure it still works.

Comment: fix ur axept r4te pls

Comment: @lunboks: Obtuse comment is obtuse.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Well, I could have said that, armed with this knowledge, people will probably just avoid using the magic word(s). Also, you should really work on your except rat.