# Display the number of up-votes along with the %accepted

Tags: feature-request, up-votes

Some people ask many questions and only accept answers. Never they give an up-vote. Meaning all the other participants to a question - who may either help or complement the accepted answer - get nothing.

That number is relative to the person activity - and should not always be displayed. But I think it is relevant in many cases (like `accept rate: 30%, upvotes: 0` where you know it is unlikely you'll get any rewarding for your work time [besides the other members of course] unless you are the accepted answer).

*edit based on comments*

Of course a user with 38% accept rate may have been unlucky with the answerers. Since we are talking about likeness, when someone has 20% accept rate, and 0 upvote after asking 50 questions, there could be a problem. Well, he may have been *very* unlucky with the answers he got, but probability-wise the odds are more keen to indicate the user is a bit tight in terms of offering recognition.

Comment: Enough users as it is are not answering just because the OP has low accept rate and it's bad for the community. We really don't need another incentive for them to not answer based on some irrelevant stat.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure that is true @sha. There has been [a steady increase in answerers over time](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/76996/number-of-users-answering-or-questioning); there has just been a larger increase in questioners. I do agree that giving people another incentive not to answer isn't good for the site (unless it's dupe).

Comment: @ben I'm not really talking about answerers in general. I see too many times comments like "I will not answer until you improve your accept rate". So having "I will not answer until you upvote more" is x10 worse.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - And I flag such comments as *obsolete* which get deleted instantly. :)

Comment: @hims056 not really instantly, it take three (or four) votes to delete a comment. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Yes but I think, a comment containing a word *accept rate* get deleted with one flag.

Comment: @hims056 lol no, REALLY hard to believe. More likely there are many users like us.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - I think *Shog9♦* commented somewhere about it. I am just finding it.

Comment: It depends whether there's the phrase "accept rate" in the comment or not @hims056...

Comment: Comments with "Improve your accept rate" will most likely get deleted by the moderator if you flag them as Not Constructive. I delete them with or without flags since we're not here to annoy people for a completely misunderstood stat. Sometimes I leave a general comment explaining that some comments about the accept rate are not welcome.

Comment: An edit has been made based on comments.

Comment: I'd rather see accept rate removed totally too. Nothing good comes from showing it there.

Comment: @Sha: It's true: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/125533/159251 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/121226/159251

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to give a strong statement: If it was for me the Accept Rate stat would be long gone. Or it would be displayed in a way that it's not misunderstood as it is now.

I'll try to explain my thoughts, hope it helps you gain yet another point of view.

I think it's going to be moved to the profile from what I've seen on MSO, so it won't be plainly visible. The problem is not the stat itself of course, rather that as I said, it's completely misunderstood. I am not aware of the rationale that has been done to implement it, but from being an innocuous stat, it has become something worse. Users see it as

> Hey, low accept rate, then he/she must not care about accepting!

While this sometimes may be true, it's not always true. And regardless of whether this is true, the accept rate doesn't tell you why that user hasn't accepted an answer for a certain question. It simply tells you "This user accepted 38% of his questions", nothing else.

The user might have not accepted because:

- There are not good enough answers yet;
- The OP is waiting for more answers;
- The OP is unsure of what answer might be worth accepting;

and so on.

With this in mind, I don't think an additional stat like the one you mention is going to be any more helpful. Perhaps it's only going to influence how people answer and we want more answers, not less.

If there is something I missed, please let me know.

Comment: An edit has been made to the feature-request based on comments

Answer (score 8):

If you care that much about an additional 10 rep from the OP you can click on their username and find out how many votes they have before deciding whether to answer.

[image]

There's already [significant debate around the accept rate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136951/lets-stop-displaying-a-users-accept-rate) and I don't really see how what you're suggesting is any different. You can get significantly more reputation from upvotes from the rest of the community than you can from the OP.

I don't believe that you should be expecting 25 reputation from the OP if your answer is accepted.

Comment: Another post to possibly mention is the [one about commenting and caring about accept rate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23321/is-it-appropriate-to-comment-on-peoples-accept-rate).

Comment: Not 25... 10 when the answer is ok but not accepted. My question was in order to avoid a click to the user profile...

Comment: @ring0 while I see your point and agree that OP should upvote good answers, we must not enforce such thing or condition answering in upvoting.

Comment: @Sha this should be an answer as it is the most relevant comment so far.

Comment: @ring0 too short as it is... will try to think of way to elaborate and if found, I'll post it.

Comment: Seems like this user also downvotes answers. Perhaps it is safest not to answer his questions.  :-)