# Acceptance rate criteria and answers with no upvotes

Tags: discussion, accept-rate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Count only questions with upvoted answers towards the accept rate percentage](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16634/count-only-questions-with-upvoted-answers-towards-the-accept-rate-percentage)

One of the requirements for a question to count toward acceptance rate is at least one answer, but that answer doesn't need upvotes. The problem with this is that if someone posts an answer that's flat out wrong or belongs as a comment on the question, the question then counts toward acceptance rate. I don't want to accept something that doesn't even resemble an answer, but not having too many questions, even a couple like this harm my acceptance rate. I realize I can delete the question, but I want to leave it in hopes that it is answered eventually.

So why not make the criterion for including questions in acceptance rate calculations at least one upvoted answer?

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate, I searched first but didn't find that.