# Accepting answers - just to keep my accept rate at 100%

Tags: discussion, questions, accept-rate

I find myself often accepting answers, even if no appropriate one is available, just to keep my accept rate at 100%.

Is there a better way? (Deleting question?) Or should I just wait longer (put a bounty)?

Comment: A non 100% accept rate is fine. Less than ~25% (depending on the number of question) is probably bad, but other than that don't fret.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unanswered questions and accept rate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/unanswered-questions-and-accept-rate)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

see:

[Count only questions with upvoted answers towards the accept rate percentage](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16634/count-only-questions-with-upvoted-answers-towards-the-accept-rate-percentage/16639#16639)

and

[Will the "Accept rate" score encourage unwanted behavior?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16712/will-the-accept-rate-score-encourage-unwanted-behavior/16716#16716)