# do closed questions work against you in your Accept Rate score?

Tags: support, closed-questions, accept-rate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does accept rate work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/how-does-accept-rate-work)

If I question is closed (in this case its because of a duplicate) and doesn't have a good answer I will obviously not accept.  Does that work against you in your "Accept Questions Pct" score?  It looks like it does and I think it shouldn't because its unclear what to do in this situation besides just leaving the question closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @Chchiray - i have flagged for deletion but no one has responded yet ?

Comment: Dude, give it some time, I'm looking at it now.  The fact that someone is looking at it 15 minutes after you posted....  *sheesh*

Comment: Patience is a virtue.

Comment: I've reopened your question, as on second viewing, it's not really a dupe (it's a new issue, but you might want to bring some of the contents of *that* question into your question).  That said, it can get new answers (or you can provide one of your own) which you can eventually accept.

Comment: Oh, and side note, this isn't a bug as you have a question as to how it works.  Those are `support`.  And the extra tags help =)

Comment: From the [FAQ on accept rate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/how-does-accept-rate-work), closed questions do not count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, closed questions are not included in the accept rate.

#### See also:

- [How does accept rate work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/how-does-accept-rate-work)
- [Count only questions with upvoted answers towards the accept rate percentage](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16634/count-only-questions-with-upvoted-answers-towards-the-accept-rate-percentage/16639#16639)

If the whole question is so bad that it's eligible for deletion, then you could just delete it youself (that works only if the question has no upvoted answers), or flag for moderator attention with the kind request to delete the question, along with an explanation of the why.